# Application not switches to Safari and not responding

Tags: ios, ipad, safari, nsurl, fast-app-switching

**WorkGround**

iPad - Landscap application.

OS Version - iOS 7.0.1

I have a `UIButton` which is added in `UITableViewCell`. On its tap it's suppose to open a URL in Safari.

```
NSURL *openURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"];
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:openURL]) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:openURL];
        });
    }
```

**Problem**

It's not opening safari, it shows a black window with animation and returns to my application, than the application hangs. If I go in background and then open application, the application behaves like normal.

I do not understand the behavior. Why is it not switching to Safari app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:openURL]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:openURL]
}
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: Thanks. But same situation happens.

Comment: I am tested it, it works for me. :S  can you test it on other device?

Comment: Yes, i know its normally working. But what i am saying is that i have this strange issue that application not react on `openURL:` method call.